# Is there a better way to write this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Like the question says is there a better way to write this:

```
SELECT clients_lists.*, 
       COUNT(clients_lists_relationships.clientid) 
FROM   clients_lists 
       LEFT JOIN clients_lists_relationships 
         ON clients_lists.listid = clients_lists_relationships.listid 
WHERE  clients_lists.parentid = 1 
GROUP  BY clients_lists.listid;
```

Comment: It looks fine. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to get a users lists and the number of members in each list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The query looks fine to me.  You can try to use aliases for better readability:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       COUNT(r.clientid) 
FROM   clients_lists c
       LEFT JOIN clients_lists_relationships r
         ON c.listid = r.listid 
WHERE  c.parentid = 1 
GROUP  BY c.listid;
```

But it won't really make a *technical* difference (not that I know).

Also make sure that both `clients_lists.listid` and `clients_lists_relationships.listid` are of the same datatype and length and are indexed. This will definitely help your query's performance.